# srand(time()) in C - calling once?

Tags: c

I've just figured out that seeding generator should be done once - e.g. in main function. Function like this:

```
int getRand(){
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    cout<<((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX))<<" ";
}
```

calling in main:

```
int main(){ 
    cout<<getlvl()<<" "<<getlvl()<<" "<<getlvl()<<" "<<getlvl();    
    return 0;
}
```

gives me the same output all the time. Why srand should be calling only once to work correctly?

Comment: Think about it not as about an RNG, but as a counter. And `srand` is resetting the counter to the given value. Now think how will it work.

Comment: also, this isn't c but c++ with c calls.

Comment: Calling `srand(1)` more than once is like saying "give me a random number from the sequence beginning with `1`" and expecting different results.

Answer (score 1):

Because `time(NULL)` doesn't have enough resolution. For every call to `srand()` there is not enough time between the calls and `time(NULL)` returns the same for every call.

So you are essentially setting the same seed for every call. If you use a more fine grained time function, with *nanoseconds* precision you might observe a difference.

If you call `srand()` once at the beginning of the program, then the seed is set to the current `time(NULL)` value and every call generates a new *pseudo*-random value. If you call the program consecutively very quickly you could observe the same problem too.

Comment: there's probably no interest calling srand more than once in a program...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's not. But some programs actually set the seed if you need to. Like some old PC games (*you could choose a given game if you previously lost it*).

Comment: the old games I know of ask to "press a key" and while doing this, they get a random value from random generator until keypress. The user _is_ the seed.